# TeamCity build fails without windows kits reference in proj file

Tags: msbuild, teamcity-9.0

I'm having an issue on teamcity (9.1.7). I don't have visual studio installed on the build server. I have installed visual studio test agents and msbuild tools. Building one of the project fails with this error-

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(694, 9): error APPX1639: File 'Windows.props' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=Portable&o2=7.0 for more information
```

The link doesn't work. After looking up the error, it seems i need to install Windows Kits and I need to add this to my csproj file under the first property group -

```
<_WindowsKitBinPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86</_WindowsKitBinPath>
<_WindowsPhoneKitBinPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\bin</_WindowsPhoneKitBinPath>
<MakePriExeFullPath>$(_WindowsKitBinPath)\makepri.exe</MakePriExeFullPath>
<MakeAppxExeFullPath>$(_WindowsKitBinPath)\makeappx.exe</MakeAppxExeFullPath>
<SignAppxPackageExeFullPath>$(_WindowsKitBinPath)\signtool.exe</SignAppxPackageExeFullPath>
<MakePriExtensionPath>$(_WindowsPhoneKitBinPath)\x86\MrmEnvironmentExtDl.dll</MakePriExtensionPath>
<MakePriExtensionPath_x64>$(_WindowsPhoneKitBinPath)\x64\MrmEnvironmentExtDl.dll</MakePriExtensionPath_x64>
```

I really don't want to add this to my csproj file. I don't know why it is required/what impact it has. Can someone explain to me why this is needed? When i build my solution locally with visual studio, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The groups of settings are basically bootstrapping parameters that are required by MSBuild in order to compile the project (A native windows phone app??). You've probably got the kit installed locally and something already integrated into Visual Studio, which is why it builds. Uninstall the Visual Studio add-in and it'll probably start failing.

You can setup your compile step to pass in these parameters without requiring them in the .csproj file if you don't want them there.

[image]

I normally abstract additional build parameters to a variable in TeamCity

[image]

Hope this helps